# how to do key board events in acrion script

Tags: actionscript-3

I have been looking up how to handle keyboard events and I've copied what they had but I still get the errors:
Line 84, Column 25  1120: Access of undefined property Keyboard.
Line 92, Column 25  1120: Access of undefined property Keyboard.
Line 95, Column 25  1120: Access of undefined property Keyboard.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import flash.events.*; //my event import
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, controls); // my event listener

        //LAUNCHER CONTROLS
    public function controls(event: KeyboardEvent):void {
        trace(event.keyCode);
        trace("hi");

        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
            //CREATE BULLET
            bullet = new Bullet(bulletLauncher.x);
            bullet.x = bullet.mX;
            bullet.y = 449;
            addChild(bullet);

        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {

        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Seems like you have to import Keyboard as well. You imported the events which will only pick up KeyboardEvent

Comment: To add, `Keyboard` class is located in `flash.ui`. So, [`import flash.ui.Keyboard;`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Keyboard.html)

Comment: Thank you this worked."Keyboard" was not being understood because I did not import flash.ui.Keyboard;